Can't bake second material to one face of object
Blender version 4.0:
I have a simple hangar structure and I've used an environment map. All the faces use the "Hangar Interior" material except for the sandy floor which should use the "Hangar Floor" Material which is nothing but the duplicate of the interior material with some wavy 'sand' texture added to it.
Everything shows perfectly in the render view, but when I am baking both the materials (yes, I've ensured the same image texture is 'selected' for both material and the floor material is 'assigned' only to the floor face) the generated texture in UV Editor screen applies the Interior texture (which has smooth sand surface) to the floor face. Why is it happening?


How exactly are you baking 2 materials at the same time?

@MartynasŽiemys thanks for your reply. I am ensuring that both materials are 'selected' by going in each slot and clicking on the Image Texture. And then I also select the target object/hangar in object mode. Then I bake it. Isn't that how it's done? This approach is working on a simple cube with the same image texture distorted "only" on one face, so I guess the environment map texture is treated differently?

I got it. It was silly of me to expect the bumps in the diffuse bake. Turns out you have to bake diffuse, normal and roughness textures first and then apply them all in the final material.
